# Tricky limit involving sine

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate
$$\text{lim}_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^4 + \text{sin}^2(y^2)}{x^4+y^4}.$$
I'm pretty sure that the limit exists and is $1$; at the very least, you get that if you approach $(0,0)$ along the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$ and $x=y$.  But I can't seem to figure out how to to show that the limit is $1$.  Thanks!

Comment: what happens when only $x=0$? I mean $\lim \frac{sin(y^2)}{y^4}$?

Comment: Try taking limits along $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ separately.

Comment: Whoops!  I wrote the problem down incorrectly.  I just fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm new to analysis, but how about you use Taylor series on  $ sin^2(x^2)$, wolfram says it's $x^4 - \frac{x^8}{3} + ... $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

$$1-{x^4+\sin^2(y^2)\over x^4+y4}={y^4-\sin^2(y^2)\over x^4+y^4}={y^4\over x^4+y^4}\left(1-{\sin^2(y^2)\over y^4} \right)$$

Now

$$\left|{y^4\over x^4+y^4}\right|\le1$$

for all $(x,y)\not=(0,0)$ and

$$\lim_{y\to0}{\sin^2(y^2)\over y^4}=\lim_{u\to0}\left({\sin u\over u}\right)^2=1$$

That should take care of things.  (Note:  the term ${y^4\over x^4+y^4}$ by itself doesn't have a limit at $(0,0)$, but it doesn't need to; all we needed was for it to be bounded.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Taylor series of $\sin^2(y^2)$ at $y=0$ gives

> $$ \sin^2(y^2) \sim y^4  . $$